# formvalidation.io dealing with generated code

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, formvalidation-plugin

I'm using [formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/) with Bootstrap in a form but I have some inputs that must be validated but aren't for some reason. Everything works except for this inputs and only when generated, if they come with the request it works fine.

**validation rule**

```
    'file_title[]': {
        message: 'O título é inválido',
        validators: {
            notEmpty: {
                message: 'O título é obrigatório e não pode estar vazio'
            },
            stringLength: {
                min: 1,
                max: 100,
                message: 'O título deve ter pelo menos 1 caracter e no máximo 100 caracteres'
            }
        }
    },
```

**form input generated**

```
<td><div class="form-group">
<input type="text" onchange="file_populate_json()" placeholder="Título" name="file_title[]" value="" class="form-control" />
</div></td>
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generate the `file_title[]` field, you should add it to the plugin in order to be validated.

To do so, add the following after the code that generate your field:

```
$('#yourFormId').formValidation('addField', 'file_title[]');
```

References:

- addField documentation: http://formvalidation.io/api/#add-field
- Example using `addField`: http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/